# Post question as Community user in Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, community-user

In Teams, how can an admin post general informative questions and answers as "Community"? It will be used as team-wide processes and wikis.

Is it possible to post something where the admin doesn't show up as the author?

Is the only solution creating another account for this type of question?